# Equivalent to LEFT() function in Google cloud data fusion data pipeline wrangler?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I need to port recipes from dataprep recipe into data fusion pipeline wrangler.

`derive type: single value: LEFT(column3, 3) as: 'column3'`

When I enter custom transform it gives me an error: 
`io.cdap.wrangler.expression.EL.compile@1:6 unsolvable function/method 'LEFT'`

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent to LEFT() in Cloud Data Fusion and CDAP is the following Directives called "cut-character".

Here is the syntax:

`cut-character <source> <destination> <type> <range|indexes>`

Here is a sample snippet that takes the first three characters from the SKU column values and transposes it to a new column named NewSKu:

`cut-character SKU NewSku 1-3`

This also can be achieved through the UI, by selecting Extract fields - using positions

[image]

Reference docs: https://docs.cask.co/cdap/current/en/user-guide/data-preparation/directives/cut-character.html

Comment: @AntoinetteF pleasure is mine, if that works out, please up vote the answer!